# Need next 6 months data in Big query from rows to columns

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have a date field in my data set where I want the sum of a column named units .where the monht name of the dates should be in column and it should be for next 6 months from current month.

Part no.   Date          Units
1213       21/9/23         1
1213       21/9/23         1
1213       21/10/23        1
1213       21/10/23        1
1213       21/11/23        1
1213       21/11/23        1
1213       21/12/23        1
1213       21/12/23        1
1213       21/12/23        1
1213       21/12/23        1

Out put

Part no. current month  current month+1 current month+2 current month+3
1213         2                 2               2             4

Comment: mysql or bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below (BigQuery)

```
select * from (
  select partNo, units, month - min(month) over() as offset
  from (
    select *, 
      12 * extract(year from date) + extract(month from date) as month
    from your_table
  )
)
pivot (sum(units) month for offset in(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]